# mesh not loading Intermediate Tutorial, Model Appearance

Tags: gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am following [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i2) tutorial from the official Gazebo web page.

In the Step 3: Importing meshes. It is not working, it doesn't load anything into Gazebo. This is my code:

```
   <visual name="top_visual">
       <pose>0 0 -0.0376785 0 0 1.5707</pose>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://velodyne_hdl32/meshes/velodyne_top.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
   </visual>
```

I have checked and I have all the files on the correct path. I only modified the **velodyne_top visual**, and this is what happends:

[image: image description]

**EDIT 1:**

Output Console:

```
[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 9.0.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.1.16
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.1.16
[Err] [InsertModelWidget.cc:336] Missing model.config for model "/home/michael/.gazebo/models/erle_gazebo_models"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16347/mesh-not-loading-intermediate-tutorial,-model-appearance/) by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-06-01**:
What's the output from the console when running `gazebo --verbose` and inserting the model?

**Comment by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) on 2017-06-01**:
Done. I have writed it in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Mesh was loading correctly, you can actually see this by **putting your mesh in a collsion** and then viewing the collisions, but wasn't being displayed. I have opened a different thread --> [click me](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16352/mesh-is-invisible-but-i-can-see-it-as-a-collision-dae-model/) <--

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) with karma: 5 on 2017-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0